# How to locate exactly that executable, which will be run if it's name entered in command line?

Tags: path, executable, locate

Is it possible to locate exactly that executable

```
myname
```

which will be run if passed to command line

```
> myname
```

`locate` command didn't work as expected, since it returns numerous results. Result should be exactly one, because if you run something, only one file runs. Also, result should take `PATH` precedence into account.

Answer (score 5):

In a shell, you would normally use `which` or `type` for this, e.g.,

```
$ bash
$ which vile
/usr/bin/vile
$ type vile
vile is /usr/bin/vile
$
```

`type` is preferred, since it works *with* a POSIX shell, while `which` is a holdover from C-shell.  In practice, I use a script showing the alternatives:

- [**`path`** — like **`which`**, but provides the dual use of showing the path and showing details about the arguments](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:path)
- [**`conflict`** — filename conflict-listing](http://invisible-island.net/conflict/conflict.html)